# button not getting pressed on picker view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, uipickerview

I am adding a button as view for row method in picker vies's delegate method. But button is not getting pressed in iOS4.0, Its working fine on iOS5.0 and above.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view 
{ 
NSArray *__autoreleasing views = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PickerRowView" owner:self options:nil]; 
self.pickerDataView = [views lastObject]; 
self.labelBtn = (UIButton *) [pickerDataView viewWithTag:101]; 
[self.labelBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(labelBtnPressed:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
return pickerDataView;


}
```

this code is working fine on iOS5 and above but not on iOS4.0. Can anyone tell why its happening??

Comment: pickerData view which i am adding as view for row consist a button, this button is not getting pressed and hence its action selector is not getting fired in iOS4.0

Comment: are you sure that in iOS4, `self.labelBtn` is not nil?

Comment: @iVishal checks self.labelBtn = (UIButton *) [pickerDataView viewWithTag:101]; then self.labelBtn  does this have any refrence <8788*22> some thing.means has refrerence...

Comment: yes m sure, same code is running fine on iOS5 and above. in iOS4.0, when i press the button, its text gets highlighted but its action doesnt get called.

Comment: @iOS-Deveoper yes it has reference , i just checked...0x6a92730

Comment: and picker view is showing button,as i can see the title of the button which i am setting dynamically..so button is not nil, its not just getting pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Just check that no other view overlapping with your buttons' view, this is the only issue which you're facing. So, try to figure-out which transparent view overlap and if possible send us the code so we can give our best to you.

Comment: picker view is subview of scrollview there is no view over picker view..and button is working fine on iOS5, had there been overlapping problem then it wont be working on iOS5.0 too. well i had to change my design but still i would like to know why button is not getting pressed in iOS4 and below versions. code i have  already posted in the question.

Comment: Well Vishal, let me make a sample code and will forward you the required url so you may sort-out problem.

Comment: Hey Vishal, due to my hard schedule,I'll take little bit time for providing you the sample but meantime do me a favor instead of adding your picker view at scroll view, you should at this to your window...I hope it'll surely help you...

Comment: hello Mohit..thank  you for taking some time for fixing my problem. I will try your solution. Thanks again :)